# how to compare the column from another table in a same query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables `td_excel` and `td_user`. I am using the following query to display records from the table `td_excel`. It have many columns but i comparing two columns `Pickup_Location` and `regional` it works perfectly,but i also want to compare the column `regional` from another table `td_user` in the same query is it possible?

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    td_excel 
where 
    `Pickup_Location` LIKE CONCAT(  '%',  `regional` ,  '%' ) OR 
    regional LIKE CONCAT(  '%',  `Pickup_Location` ,  '%' )
```

Comment: Is there a joining key between two tables ?

Comment: Is that an exact match or you need wildcard there?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty : In both tables regional has same value,but there is no joining key.

Comment: @almasshaikh : i need a exact match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try subquery like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM td_excel 
WHERE (`Pickup_Location` LIKE CONCAT(  '%',  `regional` ,  '%' ) OR 
      regional LIKE CONCAT(  '%',  `Pickup_Location` ,  '%' )) AND
      regional IN (SELECT regional
                   FROM td_user)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by joining td_user with td_excel on appropriate columns, something like this...

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    td_excel e
    JOIN td_user u
    ON <join condition>
where 
    `Pickup_Location` LIKE CONCAT(  '%',  `regional` ,  '%' ) OR 
    -- Using the regional column from td_user by qualifying the column name with the table alias
    -- declared above.
    u.regional LIKE CONCAT(  '%',  `Pickup_Location` ,  '%' )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    td_excel a inner join td_user b on a.id = b.a_id
where 
a.Pickup_Location LIKE CONCAT(  '%',  a.regional ,  '%' ) OR 
a.regional LIKE CONCAT(  '%',  a.Pickup_Location ,  '%' ) OR
b.regional LIKE CONCAT(  '%',  a.regional  ,  '%' )
```

Your forgot to tell what are the columns of td_user, so fill up this answer

Comment: `regional` is the column i want to compare from the table td_user

Comment: ahh ok, so what is the column of `td_user`

Comment: i updated my answer, pls provide the column of td_user, so that i can update the correct syntax in `ON` clause

Comment: sorry if am wrong, i have three columns to compare, first two columns are regional and Pickup_Location from td_excel and third column also regional but that is from td_user.

Comment: i updated my answer, just rename the `b.columnname` to `b.regional`

Comment: i tried this, but this displaying null values,sorry.